# Siu's 1973 paper

Tags: analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5917/5de52a12334654c4a516113c6c60ac1b3271.pdf), it's proven in 1.7 that

> If $V$ is an analytic subset of dimension $\leq q$ in an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ in $D$, then there exists an open neighborhood $U'$ of $x_0$ in $U$ such that $E_c\cap V\cap U'$ is an
>   analytic subset of $V\cap U'$.

The goal is to prove that $E_c$ is an analytic subset of $D$.

Applying the above to the trivial analytic subset $V=D$, one obtains that $E_c$ is locally analytic (i.e. $\forall x_0\in D$, there exists $U'$ such that $E_c\cap U'$ is an analytic subset of $U'$). Since there is no more explanation, it should be straightforward to deduce that $E_c$ is an analytic subset of $D$. However I couldn't do that.

How does one deduce that $E_c$ is an analytic subset of $D$?

Comment: What's the definition of an analytic subset you're working with? I think most of the time 'analytic = locally analytic', i.e., $A \subset D$ is called analytic if for any $z \in D$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $z$ in $D$ and holomorphic functions $f_1, ..., f_m$ on $V$ such that $A \cap V = \{x \in V \, | \, f_1(x) = ... = f_m(x) = 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the definition.